# Add modal window in ejs file

Tags: javascript, html, ejs, modalpopupextender, modal-window

I wrote a little program with node js and I used ejs as a template. In my program, I calculate two parameters 'msg1' and 'msg2' that I want to show on a modal window. Unfortunately I couldn't do that with ejs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, you're running the .ejs template on the server, not the client.

Anything inside `<%  %>` runs as part of the template, which means it's trying to call `alert` in the server. This should fail.

You haven't said what `msg1` and `msg2` are. If they're client-side variables then all you need is:

```
function alertNumber() {
    alert(msg1 + msg2)
}
```

which would mean you don't even need templating - it's just an HTML file. On the other hand, if `msg1` and `msg2` are server-side variables, they need to be inserted using the template. A naive way of doing so would be like this:

```
function alertNumber() {
    alert('<%- msg1 + msg2 %>')
}
```

This only works if `msg1 + msg2` doesn't contain the characters `'`, `\`, newline, carriage return, and possibly others I've missed. If it does, the script will probably fail. In particular, don't do this unless `msg1` and `msg2` are from a trusted source, because whoever controls them will be able to inject any javascript code they want into the client. However, if you can guarantee that they're numbers then this won't be a problem.

Last but not least... you've defined `alertNumber`. Have you actually used this function?

Comment: I don't know why it failed. What library are you using for templating? How are you calling the template function? And you misunderstand 'inject' - I meant it may be insecure. For example, if `msg2` is `5');stealUserData();('`, the script may say `alert('15');stealUserData();('')`. If I get more time I may write more. When I asked if you've used the function, I meant it looks like you've defined it but not called it. E.g. if you write `$(alertNumber);` it should call the function when the page loads (you may also need `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>`).

Comment: Do you realise `msg1` and `msg2` need to be imported into the template explicitly? For example, (in lodash) `_.template("<html>...</html>", {imports:{msg1:38,msg2:'expires on Tuesday'}})`.